# pdfsplit vs pdftk, split pdf into chunks

Tags: python, command-line

So I am on a mac trying to do `pdftk mypdf.pdf burst output /Users/user/Desktop/page_%02d.pdf` however, this creates one empty file and the command never get executed properly but just stands still in terminal, anyone seen something similar?

So i installed [pdfsplit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfsplit/) but I cannot find anything about how to split the pdf into chunks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when updating to sierra, use the pdftk provided from below and install it through brew.

`brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/turforlag/homebrew-cervezas/master/pdftk.rb`